# Keychain returns different values in each call

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I have a class which saves an `NSDictionary` into **KeyChain**. It worked fine but suddenly, when I try to load the `NSDictionary` I get nil value.

This is the class:

```
//
//  KeyChainHandler.m
//
//

#import "KeyChainHandler.h"

#define IDENTIFIER @"Identifier"

@interface KeyChainHandler ()

@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSDictionary *applicationData;

@end

@implementation KeyChainHandler

// Make this class a singleton
static KeyChainHandler *instance = nil;

+ (KeyChainHandler*)sharedKeyChain
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self load];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)saveObject:(NSDictionary*)data
{
    self.applicationData = data;
    [self storeDictionary:data toKeychainWithKey:IDENTIFIER];
}

- (NSDictionary*)load
{
    NSDictionary *data = [KeyChainHandler dictionaryFromKeychainWithKey:IDENTIFIER];
    self.applicationData = data;
    return data;
}

- (void)remove
{
    [self deleteDictionaryFromKeychainWithKey:IDENTIFIER];
}

- (void)storeDictionary:(NSDictionary*)data toKeychainWithKey:(NSString*)aKey
{
    // serialize dict
    NSData *serializedDictionary = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:data];
    // encrypt in keychain
    // first, delete potential existing entries with this key (it won't auto update)
    [self remove];

    // setup keychain storage properties
    NSDictionary *storageQuery = @{
                                   (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount:    aKey,
                                   (__bridge id)kSecValueData:      serializedDictionary,
                                   (__bridge id)kSecClass:          (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                   (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible: (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked
                                   };
    OSStatus osStatus = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)storageQuery, nil);
    if(osStatus != noErr) {
        // do someting with error
    }
}


+ (NSDictionary*)dictionaryFromKeychainWithKey:(NSString *)aKey
{
    // setup keychain query properties
    NSDictionary *readQuery = @{
                                (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount: aKey,
                                (__bridge id)kSecReturnData: (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                                (__bridge id)kSecClass:      (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword
                                };

    CFDataRef serializedDictionary = NULL;
    OSStatus osStatus = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)readQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&serializedDictionary);
    if(osStatus == noErr) {
        // deserialize dictionary
        NSData *data = (__bridge NSData *)serializedDictionary;
        NSDictionary *storedDictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        return storedDictionary;
    }
    else {
        // do something with error
        return nil;
    }
}


- (void)deleteDictionaryFromKeychainWithKey:(NSString*)aKey
{
    // setup keychain query properties
    NSDictionary *deletableItemsQuery = @{
                                          (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount:        aKey,
                                          (__bridge id)kSecClass:              (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                          (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit:         (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitAll,
                                          (__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes:   (id)kCFBooleanTrue
                                          };

    CFArrayRef itemList = nil;
    OSStatus osStatus = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)deletableItemsQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&itemList);
    // each item in the array is a dictionary
    NSArray *itemListArray = (__bridge NSArray *)itemList;
    for (NSDictionary *item in itemListArray) {
        NSMutableDictionary *deleteQuery = [item mutableCopy];
        [deleteQuery setValue:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
        // do delete
        osStatus = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)deleteQuery);
        if(osStatus != noErr) {
            // do something with error
        }
    }
}

@end
```

At `AppDelegate` when I print `[[KeyChainHandler sharedHandler] load];` I get the correct data, then on login screen I try to do it again and I get `nil`. Then when I restart (just with CMD + R) the app, I don't get `nil`, I get the correct data again..

What seems to be the problem? maybe it's some kind of Apple's bug?

Comment: Is the error on the Simulator or device? Why is this a Singleton? Why is there the property `applicationData` since it is never accessed, only set?

Comment: It's on device. But in one it's working and the other it's not. the applicationData is accessed from another class.

Comment: Ah, the @interface is not in the question.

Comment: This code looks fine but you shouldn't just ignore errors - at least print them to console to see whether there is a problem or not. I guess you will have a problem somewhere else. Maybe you are removing the key somwhere in your app?

Comment: Also, I believe that you should always use `kSecAttrService` because an item is actually identified by the pair of `kSecAttrService` and `kSecAttrAccount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why: call `[[KeyChainHandler sharedHandler] load];`, the property is already loaded at singleton creation and if changed the property would also be updated.

You do need to set the property to `nil` in `remove`.

Instead just use:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [KeyChainHandler sharedKeyChain].applicationData;
```

Note: the code is: `sharedKeyChain`, the example call is: `sharedHandler`.